# CI. PHP. Dynamic Text watermark returns white box and no image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, watermark

I am trying to watermark a png or jpg image with some text. I am using Codeigniter image_lib but I have also tried to do it with PHP only. It works in both cases when it is not dynamic, but if the dynamic option is enabled, then it doesn't work.
Here my attempts:
With PHP:

```
    $imgpath='../assets/uploads/11/';
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($imgpath.$filename);
    //figure out where to put the text
    $x_offset = 7;
    $y_offset = 7;  
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    imagestring($im, 5, $x_offset, $y_offset, 'watermark text goes here', $textcolor);
    //output watermarked image
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagejpeg($im);
```

With Codeigniter image_lib:

```
function watermark_image() 
{
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $imgpath='../assets/uploads/11/';
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    //Put them all together to get the full path to the image:
    $config['source_image']     = $imgpath.$filename; 
    $config['wm_text']          = date(now());
    $config['wm_type']          = 'text';
    $config['wm_font_path']     = './fonts/arial-webfont.ttf';
    $config['wm_font_size']     = 16;
    $config['wm_font_color']    = 'ffffff';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
    $config['wm_padding']       = '20';
    $config['dynamic_output']   = TRUE;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

}
```

But it only outputs a white box:
[Box displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrMsL.png)

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No. Didn't find a solution.

Comment: I found there was a couple of characters being output before the image was sent. Calling `ob_clean();` before outputting the file solved the issue. If it helps I can add an answer incase anyone has similar issues